# How can I redirect to a PHP page with an <a> tag? Also how can I pass an ID number through the URL with it?

Tags: php, http-redirect

For my PHP project I am using a post method for the form and I want to be able to redirect to a PHP page with an `<a>` tag.

This is the code that I want to use to redirect, but I don't know how to make it work with the `<a>` tag.

```
$query_string = ['item' => $_SESSION['items']];
$url_query = http_build_query($query_string);
header("location:detailPage.php?$url_query");
```

Also, How can I pass an ID number through the URL from the current page to a different PHP page?

Comment: Simple close php tags and then `<a href="detailPage.php?<?php echo $url_query; ?>">Any Text</a>`

Comment: Why do you want to use `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `html` tag with embedded `php` code

```
<a href="detailPage.php?id=<?php echo $url_query; ?>">TEXT</a>
```

in `detailPage.php` you will call it like

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])//getting id from url using $_GET request
{
   $id = $_GET['id'];//storing in php variable
}
```

I hope this will help you. If there is anything wrong kindly let me know